# arrays are not functioning depending on their format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that responds differently depending on the way I set up the array that it is taking as an input. For the non-working ways, the function still runs, but just not correctly

working way:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = ["something1", "a,b,c,9", "more", "b,c,4"]
array2 = ["something2", "4,3", "more", "1,a"]
array3 = ["something3", "z", "more", "9,1"]
array4 = ["something4", "1", "more", "z"]
real_array = np.array((array1,array2,array3,array4))
```

not working way:

```
import numpy as np
array = [["something1", "a,b,c,9", "more", "b,c,4"],["something2", "4,3", "more", "1,a"],["something3", "z", "more", "9,1"],["something4", "1", "more", "z"]]
real_array = np.array((array))
```

similar not working way:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
array = []
reading = csv.reader(open('file.csv', 'rb'))
for row in reading:
    array.append(row)
real_array = np.array((array))
```

clearly the not working way would be easier for dealing with data because I can append the rows to `array` and the other way must be done manually.

---

**Both arrays are identical...so why is my function responding to them differently?**

---

My function randomly chooses a row from a file and then checks to see if something in the second column matches something in the last column of the **previous choice**. Here it is:

```
def make_sequence(size,array):
        count = 0
        without_column = array[1::]
        np.random.shuffle(without_column)
        sequence = [without_column[0]]
        result = [without_column[0][0]]
        length = 0
        while length < size:
            np.random.shuffle(without_column)
            start = without_column[0][1].split(',')
            end = sequence[count][3].split(',')
            i = 0
            while i < len(start):
                if start[i] in end:
                    sequence.append(without_column[0])
                    result.append(without_column[0][0])
                    count += 1
                    i = len(start)
                else:
                    pass
                i += 1
            length = len(result)
        return result
```

---

EDIT 2: What should happen

---

if I do this code:

```
make_sequence(10,real_array)
```

I want it to return an array that is different every time and is made up of the 1st column only, but will only place items next to each other if the starting position of the 2nd item is one of the ending positions of the 1st. Here is an example:

If the first item chosen is array3, the next item can only be array1 or array4, none of the others. This is because column 4 for array 3 is 9,1 meaning that the only arrays that can come after that must have a 9 or a 1 in their 2nd column.

so if the randomly chosen first item is array3, then if I run this code:

```
make_sequence(2,real_array)
```

could only have the following output possibilities:

["something3","something4"]

["something3","something1"]

Comment: have looked at [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) and [`numpy.genformtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?

Comment: @root I hadn't, but I tried it and it is not working properly with the function.

Comment: @MattiJohn the first example is a correct example. And I should have actually done the arrays differently, because with the examples I gave, it wont work as inputs to the actual function. Hold on

Comment: The first example and the second example produce identical results.

Comment: If you try now, it wont work properly. before all of the second columns and the last columns were the same so the function treated them equally.

Comment: @Robᵩ Did you try that before I changed the values of the arrays? Because then it would have.

Comment: No, I tried it after. Download and run [this program](http://ideone.com/UBqyGj) -- you should see that the two versions produce identical results.

Comment: Okay...then how come when I run it through my function, it reads it differently depending on which way I do it

Comment: I'm not sure what your function is supposed to do, so I can't really say. I do notice that it calls `np.random.shuffle()`, so I'd *expect* it to produce different results. Perhaps you could post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). My guess is that you will discover the problem while creating the SSCCE.

Comment: Also, I notice that `make_sequence()` modifies the array. Perhaps it should make a deep copy first?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to produce different results, but the second method is producing faulty results while the first is not. And the copy didn't make a difference :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution! The function works perfectly if I just don't run the files into a numpy array at all...here is what worked:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
array = []
reading = csv.reader(open('file.csv', 'rb'))
for row in reading:
    array.append(row)
make_sequence(10,array)
```

If I do not convert the array to a numpy array, my function works perfectly.

**I still do not know why this is and if anybody knows, please tell me**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your arrays seem identical to me.  In addition to Rob's test, you can also see that

```
real_array1.shape == real_array2.shape
real_array1.dtype == real_array2.dtype
```

Both return `True`

However, your function uses a random line, of course it will return different results each time.  I'm not sure, without a more careful reading, what your code is supposed to do, but your problem might be that your `without_column` array is actually the array without the first *row*.

```
In [15]: without_column = real_array1[1::]

In [16]: real_array1
Out[16]: 
array([['something1', 'a,b,c,9', 'more', 'b,c,4'],
       ['something2', '4,3', 'more', '1,a'],
       ['something3', 'z', 'more', '9,1'],
       ['something4', '1', 'more', 'z']], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [17]: without_column
Out[17]: 
array([['something2', '4,3', 'more', '1,a'],
       ['something3', 'z', 'more', '9,1'],
       ['something4', '1', 'more', 'z']], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

Perhaps what you want is:

```
In [19]: without_column = real_array1[:,1:]

In [20]: without_column
Out[20]: 
array([['a,b,c,9', 'more', 'b,c,4'],
       ['1', 'more', 'z'],
       ['z', 'more', '9,1'],
       ['4,3', 'more', '1,a']], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

Is this intended?

---

When I try to run your code, choosing `size` > 1 makes the while loop run forever.

Comment: I know that is not where the issue is...in the large csv I am reading from, column one is labels. I could have used `.next()`, but I didn't. From looking at examples, it will run forever if columns 2 or 4 have only 1 thing (array4) rather than multiple (array2)...why would that be happening

Answer (score -1):

Both arrays are **not** identical. The non-working array is a multi-dimensional array, not a standard array.

Comment: then how come [this program](http://ideone.com/UBqyGj) that Rob commented is returning true? And if that is really the reason why my function is not working, why and how can I fix it?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Although the two arrays technically aren't the same, I see what you mean. Can you post your function's code?

Comment: It is posted at the bottom of my question

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Busy right now. Will reply later. Can you post a sample file and usage?

Comment: I have added an example now

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Does the array really need to be a numpy array? Or can your function do that, instead of the user?